# How to Read the text from a JPG or PNG file with pandas or numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

While learning through pandas & numpy i have learned lost across from the SO, Just looking forward for the way of reading a JPG or PICS and get the data into the text form from it.

I searched around the goggled a lot but did not get the way of doing this in pandas or numpy, sorry if i have overlooked during my searched..

Just adding the screen below for the sake of an example..

[image]

Comment: As far as I know, neither `pandas` or `numpy` have such functionality.

Comment: Look for **tesseract** or **pytesseract** and **OCR**.